# Override Delete button/link with VF page

Tags: javascript, button-overrides, delete

I'm trying to override the custom Account button links to allow users to merge Accounts while only allowing SysAdmins the ability to delete  accounts. I had a working version of this earlier but now my page is stuck on a refresh loop when I go to delete an account as an admin.

Has anyone implemented a solution similar to this? I don't think a trigger would work because the merge function needs to be able to delete one of the merging records.

Here is my VF page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="CheckDelete" action="{!checkDelete}">

Unfortunately you  do not have access to delete this account.
Click&nbsp; <apex:outputLink value="/{!Account.id}">here</apex:outputLink> to return to the account page. 
</apex:page>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public class CheckDelete 
{
   private ApexPages.standardcontroller stdCtrl;
   public CheckDelete(ApexPages.Standardcontroller std)
   {
       stdCtrl=std;
   }

   public PageReference checkDelete()
   {
      Id ProID = userinfo.getProfileId(); 
        string pName = [Select Name From Profile Where Id =: ProID].Name;
      if (pName == 'System Administrator')
      {
          return stdCtrl.delete();
      }
      else
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is being redirected from the Visualforce override back onto the Visualforce override. To allow this code to work, you need to set the "nooverride" parameter:

```
PageReference ref = stdCtrl.delete();
ref.getParameters().put("nooverride","1"); // Any value will do
return ref;
```

Unfortunately, as you may expect, this isn't the preferred way to do this. Why? Because, obviously, if your code can add a simple parameter, your users can also add the same parameter. Visualforce overrides are not preferable to triggers for enforcing this type of logic.

Thankfully, it so happens that you can detect when a record is being deleted versus merged. It works like this:

```
trigger protectDelete on Account (after delete) {
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
    for(Account record: Trigger.old) {
        if(p.Id != UserInfo.getProfileId() && record.MasterRecordId == null) {
            record.addError('You do not have permission to delete accounts.');
        }
    }
}
```

`MasterRecordId` is a field that is set on the "losing" record of a merge that indicates the ID of the surviving record. If this field is null, then it is a true delete, otherwise this is a merge function.